# Kindle app on ubuntu 17.10

Tags: wine, amazon, kindle

so amazon wants to have an icon pinned on all ubuntus but when comes time to release it's flagship app it's windows and mac only?

I digress

I like calibre so far but just in case and for the sake of geeking out over making it work, is there a way to run it via wine?

I tried this fix : https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1913348&p=11631859#post11631859

and in this case I did the same for the 64bit twin of the file in question since since my wine is 64bit it's probably running in 64bit mode by default.

I currently am running wine-3.0 (stable) ubuntu 17.10 64bit with all updates as of 12/02/2018

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need [PlayOnLinux](https://www.playonlinux.com/en/app-1265-Amazon_Kindle.html). Open terminal and type  `sudo apt-get install playonlinux winbind -y` and search for Amazon Kindle in the software. Select Amazon Kindle and then install.

Answer (score 0):

I can install it via WineTricks without issue, I can sign in after using an OTP from Amazon, but Help, Check for Problems shows no internet connectivity and I cannot sync my library.

The fix listed above doesn't change anything for me.  Ubuntu 16.04 LTS.

Anyone else with ideas?

Comment: Please don't ask a question in a answer, [Post a new question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/ask) instead.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the connectivity issues on a Surface Pro tablet. The device and user must establish an association with the Amazon account. It appears that Amazon forces the issue in order to pair the device with the account.  Next you have to play email tag where Amazon will send you a temp login id in order to connect the Amazon-kindle.  Note: Since then, I can only use kindle if online.  No more offline utility. This will get the Kindle app decommissioned.